# Agregar un elemento a un tabla de HTML con javaScript teniendo como base de datos a MONGOdb

Tags: javascript, html, css, base-de-datos, mongodb

he estado programando para mi proyecto final una pagina en donde se guarde en una base de datos una hora y fecha de los ayunos realizados(se utiliza mongodb para poder guardar los datos ), pero no he encontrado un codigo java que me pueda servir para poder insertar la hora y fecha a una tabla, realmente les agradeceria una ayuda me urge entregar este proyecto y cualquier comentario me seria de ayuda.

nota: ya se creo las respectivas carpetas para poder conectar con mongodb via localhost8080, el problema esta en el codigo java.

son 2 paginas, la primera es para llenar el formulario y en la segunda pagina es para ver el resultado:

primera pagina html se llama (ayuno.html):

```
        <div class="fecha">
            <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
        </div>

        <div onload="cargarTabla()" id="tablaHoras"class="horayAgregarAyuno">

            <div id="hora" class="hora">
                <select name="horas" id="horasTotales">
                    <option class="horas14">14horas</option>
                    <option class="horas16">16horas</option>
                    <option class="horas18">18horas</option>
                    <option class="horas20">20horas</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="agregarAyuno">
                <a  id="agregarAyuno" onclick="insertarHora()" href="mes.html">Agregar ayuno</a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <script src="ayuno.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

la segunda pagina html en donde deberia aparecer el contenido agregado:

```
**<div id="tablaHoras" class=" tablaHoras wrapper">
    <tr>
      <dt id="horasTotales" ></dt>
      <dt>Horas Totales</dt>
      <dt id="fecha"></dt>
    </tr>
    <script src="ejemplo.js"></script>
</div>**
```

por ultimo tengo el codigo de javaScript:

```
function cargarTabla() {
fetch("http://localhost:8080/ayuno/")
  .then(
    function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
    })
    .then(
    function (json) {
            for(var cont = 0;json.length > cont; cont++) 
            {
    var linea = "<tr><td>"+json[cont]._id+"</td><td>"+json[cont].fecha+"</td><td>"+json[cont].horasTotales+"</td></tr>";
     document.getElementById("tablaHoras").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", linea);
            }
        })
    }


function insertarHora(){

  var datos = {
    fecha: document.getElementById("fecha").value,
    horasTotales : document.getElementById("horasTotales").value
  }

  fetch("http://localhost:8080/ayuno/insertar",{
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(datos),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  })
    .then(
      function(response){
      return response.json();
      }
    )

    .then(
      function(json){
      var linea = "<tr><td>"+json[cont]._id+"</td><td>"+json[cont].fecha+"</td><td>"+json[cont].horasTotales+"</td></tr>";
      document.getElementById("tablaHoras").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", linea);
      }
    )
}
```

La vdd he visto muchos tutoriales y codigo y no encuentro el fallo.

Comment: Pero... el que inserta los datos en la base de datos es el que procesa esta URL: http://localhost:8080/ayuno/insertar...

Comment: si exacto pipe, con esa URL inserto la base de datos pero no se como hacer para que aparezca en la otra pagina que se llama mes.html

Comment: Pero la función ya la tienes... Se llama cargarTabla... Te sale algun error al usarla?

Comment: si, en realidad no me sale la tabla